# Mail app keeps freezing (Jelly Bean 4.1.2 on Samsung Galaxy S3)

Tags: email, samsung-galaxy-s-3

Mail app keeps freezing (Jelly Bean 4.1.2 on Samsung Galaxy S3).

Really annoying since I use it for work mail.

Comment: Is this the first time it happened?

Comment: Did you try to clear its cache (maybe something got messed up there)? Also, some additional context would help to locate the problem. With the current phrasing, all we can say is we feel sorry for you...

Comment: I use the "out of the box" email app to connect to our exchange server. When I click on the "email" icon, I see all the current mail, but, when I click on the mail nothing happens. About 2 minutes later I get a popup stating "Mail is not responding, do you want to close it."  I updated to jellybean yesterday.  Never had this issue with the old Ice Cream software. What other intor might you need?

Comment: This has been going on ever since I upgraded to Jelly Bean 4.1.1 (not 4.1.2)

Comment: This is happening on my S3 too since the 4.1.2 upgrade